# How to close firefox browser in selenium 3.0.1

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, geckodriver, selenium3, firefox-driver

Firefox : 50.0.1, GeckoDriver :13, selenium 3.01,  IDE: Eclipse, Programming language : Java

Using below code :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\geckodriver.exe); 
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/");
driver.close(); Or driver.quit()
```

In driver.close() the browser is not closed
In driver.quite() the browser is closed and Firefox crashed.
Getting Error: "plugin container for FireFox has stopped working."

Please let me know any solution

Answer (score 1):

Steps you can try:

1. Uninstall any plugins in the Firefox browser.
2. Use the 64-bit version of geckodriver for 64-bit Firefox, similarly, 32-bit geckodriver for 32-bit Firefox.

I have tried the code in the **same** environment, and `driver.quit` worked for me. `driver.close` still not closing the browser.

Comment: when you used driver.quite, was it not giving any Error as ''Firefox is stopped working"

Comment: Yes, it closed properly and not crashed.

Comment: did you uninstalled all plugins in firefox browser ..?

Comment: No. Disabled all of them. First, try with disabling. Maybe one of the plugin causing the issue, if not all.

Comment: any luck? do a system restart and try once. Don't ask me the logic. sometimes, it works like a magic.

Answer (score 1):

You should always use `driver.quit()` when you want to close browser and not just one tab.

This exception you get is unfortunately known issue when quitting geckodriver firefox instance, see this links for details.

https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/7506
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1027222

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new firefox profile steps can be found [here](https://www.guru99.com/firefox-profile-selenium-webdriver.html)!

In your code use this new profile created.

```
WebDriver webdriver;
ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile myprofile = profile.getProfile("myProfileName");
webdriver = new FirefoxDriver(myprofile);
```

Now webdriver.quit(); will close the firefox browser after the test has run.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem with the geckodriver.

The workaround which worked for me was to install the older version of geckodriver, 0.20.1, which you can download here: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.20.1